# getchar in a Programm that counts the Frequency of Characters in a String

Tags: c

I wrote a program that finds the frequency of Characters in a String, when I add the getchar() function the frequency is always 1 even when its not, but when I don't use getchar() the program works perfectly. does any one have a reason why this happens ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

char a[30],c;
int i,t=0;

printf("Enter your sentence:");
fgets(a, 30, stdin);
printf("%s",a);


printf("Enter the charahter you want to check:");
scanf("%c",&c);
c = getchar();


for(i=0; a[i] != '\0';i++)
{
  if (a[i] == c) ++t; 

}
printf("the frecuncey of the charachter %c is :%d",c,t);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're assigning the result of `getchar` to `c`, discarding the value that was obtained from `scanf`.  You're probably picking up a newline character, which would explain why you're getting 1.

Comment: How is this question different to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118775/c-program-to-find-the-frequency-of-characters-in-a-word-here-is-what-i-did) ?

Comment: `getchar` is not the problem, `scanf` is.

Comment: Why do you need two subsequent input operations for the same task?

Answer (score 0):

You are scanning character two times for character that used for check.

Comment one of lines:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
c = getchar();
```

Basically the character you wanted to check is goes in to c by scanf, but will goes new character in c by getchar which may be a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a reason why this happens?

#### 1.

`fgets()` catches the newline character (made by the press to `Return`) when you input the string which you want to check for a specific character.

#### 2.

By:

```
c = getchar();
```

the left newline character from the previous

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

is read into `c`.

#### 3.

Thereafter if you check the string for `c` which contains the newline character (`\n`) in the `for` loop, the result is `1` because the string contains the newline character catched by `fgets()`.

---

The two subsequent input operations for the character to `check` cause that behavior.

Maybe your intention was to catch the left newline character (`\n`) from `stdin` made by the call to `scanf(%c,&a)` but the issue is here that you assign the return value of `getchar()` (which is actually the newline) to `c` which is  wrong.

---

The corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   char a[30],c;
   int i,t=0;

   printf("Enter your sentence: ");
   fgets(a, 30, stdin);
   printf("%s",a);

   printf("Enter the character you want to check: ");
   scanf("%c",&c);
   getchar();              // only getchar() without to assigning its return value


   for(i=0; a[i] != '\0';i++)
   {
      if (a[i] == c) ++t; 
   }
   printf("The frequency of the character %c is: %d",c,t);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter your sentence: hello world and stack overflow          
hello world and stack overflow                      
Enter the character you want to check: o       
The frequency of the character o is: 4
```